# Change/set new position of a node during the simulation time in Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I have a simulation that currently has BonnMotionMobility, where I tell where nodes will be during simulation. But I want that, as a consequence of some events, some nodes change their positions to another position during the simulation.
Is there any function to "set a new position" that can be called somewhere in the middle of the running simulation (some reactive mobility model)?

I hope I was clear enough on my problem.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Could you show a [mcve], please? It's hard to comment on code you cannot see.

Comment: I am just asking if there is a method to set a new position of a node during simulation. but it can be something like: if(istrue){ setnewposition(node[1], 10,10);}

Comment: Please consider that your audiance may have *no idea* what kind of simulation you are talking about. Also your question really should tell the audience what "Omnet" is. And finally, without a [mcve], most people will be hard pressed to answer, even if they know all the acronyms. All I'm saying is: make your question easy to answer by helping your audience :)

Comment: To answer my problem, a bit of knowledge and experience on omnet is required. If they don't even know  what omnet is, then they unfortunately can't help. In this case I ask a direct question, it is of no big use a code of "minimal reproducible example". Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that way. If you want to implement your own logic how nodes should move, you should implement your own mobility model (deriving from MovingMobilityBase or something appropriate). You should pass all the needed information the mobility module i.e. send events or signals there and the movement logic should be handled inside the mobility module. In the current architecture, determining the location of the module is the sole responsibility of the mobility module.

What you are suggesting is (by looking for a setCoordinates() like function) is that you want to move that responsibility out into other unrelated modules which is usually not a good decision.

In short, you should write your own mobility module that does that. Obviously you can write a simple model that has a setCoordinates() function and call that from your other code.